Get-MgUserCalendar fails with "The specified object was not found in the store." for my own calendar
I'm trying to access my own calendar via powershell but am getting an error:
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Calendar

$creds = Get-Credential -UserName "<my user name>"

# Get list of available graph scopes
Connect-MgGraph
Get-MgContext | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Scopes
   
$userId = (Get-MgUser -Filter "Mail eq '$($creds.UserName)'").Id

# Get calendar permissions
Find-MgGraphCommand -command Get-MgUserCalendar | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Permissions

Get-MgUserCalendar -UserId $userId

Results:
Get-MgUserCalendar_List: The specified object was not found in the store.
Status: 404 (NotFound)
ErrorCode: ErrorItemNotFound

The Get-MgContext | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Scopes returns:
Application.Read.All
Application.ReadWrite.All
Calendars.Read.Shared
DelegatedPermissionGrant.ReadWrite.All
openid
Policy.ReadWrite.PermissionGrant
profile
User.Read
User.ReadWrite.All
email

The Find-MgGraphCommand returned this:
Name                  IsAdmin Description                               FullDescription
----                  ------- -----------                               ---------------
Calendars.ReadBasic   False   Consent name unavailable                  Consent description unavailable
Calendars.Read.Shared False   Read calendars you can access             Allows the app to read events in all calendars…
Calendars.ReadWrite   False   Read and write calendars in all mailboxes Allows the app to create, read, update, and de…
Calendars.Read        False   Read calendars in all mailboxes           Allows the app to read events of all calendars…

It seems I have the access, but the error isn't helpful. Any suggestions?
Updates:

Powershell version 7.4.5
Microsoft.Graph version 2.23.0

Graph calendar results:

Get-MgUserCalendar results:


Could you confirm whether you are getting results when you run GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars query in Graph Explorer by signing in with your user like this https://i.imgur.com/aCowElw.png ?

@sridevi I was able to view my calendar and see the same results you did after granting it Calendar.Read.Shared permission in the Permission Panel.

Then it should work with Powershell commands too. Could you try including scopes with Connect-MgGraph -Scopes Calendars.Read.Shared and sign in interactively with your account and check. Please include the response image by editing your question

When I ran below query in Graph Explorer, I got the response successfully with signed-in user's calendars details like this:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars

Response:

To get the same details via Microsoft Graph PowerShell, try including scopes parameter like Connect-MgGraph -Scopes Calendars.Read.Shared and sign in interactively with your account like this:
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes Calendars.Read.Shared
Get-MgContext | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Scopes
   
$userId = (Get-MgUser -Filter "Mail eq 'sri@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com'").Id

Find-MgGraphCommand -command Get-MgUserCalendar | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Permissions

Get-MgUserCalendar -UserId $userId

Running above script opens browser and asks user to pick an account like this:

While signing in, I got below consent screen to allow user for accessing calendars:

After successful authentication, it gives below screen in browser saying "Authentication complete" like this:

When I checked the output now, I got the response successfully with signed-in user's calendars details like this:


I'm still getting the same error. When I run the script like you have it above, I do not get prompted for authentication in the browser at all.  Find-MgGraphCommand returns same output as yours, and Connect-MgGraph does return Calendars.Read.Shared in my output. Any other suggestions?

Could you confirm where you are running the powershell code and what powershell version you are using? Please edit your question by adding images

I'm running latest powershell version and graph version, in PowerShell 7 (x64) command line.  Images are added to original question.

I guess user authentication is not working properly as you are not getting any login prompt when you run Connect-MgGraph. Could you try running Disconnect-MgGraph and see with which user you previously logged in and try running the script in answer again after disconnecting MS Graph?

Thank you, that was it!  I have a user and admin account, and apparently I was signed in with the admin account for whatever reason.  I can see my calendar now, thank you.

@Greg Glad to know it worked
